# VectorUDT usage

Tags: apache-spark, vector, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have to get the datatype and do a case match and convert it to some required format. But the usage of `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT` is showing `VectorUDT` is `private`. Also I specifically need to use `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT` and not `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT`. Can someone suggest how to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

For `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg` types you should specify schema using `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes` [which provide singleton instances of the private `UDT` types](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/SQLDataTypes.scala#L29-L36):

- [`MatrixType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes$@MatrixType:org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType) for matrices (`org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Matrix`).

  ```
  scala> org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes.MatrixType.getClass
  res0: Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType] = class org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.MatrixUDT
  ```
- [`VectorType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes$@VectorType:org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType) for vectors (`org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector`).

  ```
  scala> org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes.VectorType.getClass
  res1: Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType] = class org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT
  ```