# Error while converting Vector to dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

Error while converting Vector to a data frame

The code mentioned in first part works well but it is a non-intuitive way to convert vector data into a data frame.

I would like to solve this with what I know i.e. Code mentioned in second part.
Could you please assist

```
val data = Seq(
      Vectors.sparse(4, Seq((0, 1.0), (3, -2.0))),
      Vectors.dense(4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 3.0),
      Vectors.dense(6.0, 7.0, 0.0, 8.0),
      Vectors.sparse(4, Seq((0, 9.0), (3, 1.0)))
    )   

val tupleList = data.map(Tuple1.apply)
val df = rdd.toDF("features")
```

Can't we do simply like below

```
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(data).map(a => Row(a))
rdd.take(1)

val fields = "features".split(" ").map(fields => StructField(fields,DoubleType, nullable =true))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, StructType(fields))
df.count()
```

But I am getting an error as below

```
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: double]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 357.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 357.0 (TID 1243, datacouch, executor 3): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector is not a valid external type for schema of double
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, features), DoubleType) AS features#6583
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:586)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:586)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
```

Comment: @user8371915 please read my question first

Answer (score 1):

As clearly explained in [VectorUDT usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809316/vectorudt-usage) and in exception you get, the correct `DataType` for `Vector` is `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes.VectorType`:

```scala
spark.createDataFrame(
  rdd, 
  StructType(Seq(
    StructField("features", org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes.VectorType)
  ))
)
```